# SQL Sub-query Error

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

I think there is issue with the A2 set where I am only including Restart_case = Y, but I am not sure please help. I am getting this error: An unexpected token "WHERE" was found following "_ID) AS Max_DateBegin".  Expected tokens may include...
Thank you

```
SELECT A2.* FROM
(SELECT A1.*, min(BeginDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Per_ID) AS Min_BeginDate,
MAX(BeginDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Per_ID) AS Max_BeginDate
WHERE RestartCase = 'Y'
From) A2
(SELECT distinct C.Per_ID, P.DOB, C.BeginDate, C.EndDate, C.RestartCase, P.per_type
FROM CaseSum C LEFT JOIN PERSON p on C.ID_PRSN = P.ID_PRSN)  A1
WHERE per_Type = 1 AND BeginDate <= '9/30/2017' AND (EndDate >= '10/01/2017' OR EndDate IS NULL)
ORDER BY A1.Per_ID
```

Comment: For starters you have no table specified in the `FROM` for A2. After that I'm confused because you have 2 derived tables but they aren't joined so I'm not sure what you are doing.

Comment: @SQLChao I am new to SQL and what I am trying to do is getting the result from A1 so I can do some calculations (min date and max date) with RestartCase condition. I don't know how I can write this type of query, so I just tried and come up with this. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name DB2

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want (or something like it):

`SELECT 
    A2.* 
FROM
    (SELECT 
        A1.*, 
        MIN(BeginDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Per_ID) AS Min_BeginDate,
        MAX(BeginDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Per_ID) AS Max_BeginDate
    FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
            C.Per_ID, 
            P.DOB, 
            C.BeginDate, 
            C.EndDate, 
            C.RestartCase, 
            P.per_type
        FROM CaseSum C 
        LEFT JOIN PERSON P 
            on C.ID_PRSN = P.ID_PRSN
        WHERE P.per_Type = 1 
            AND C.BeginDate <= '9/30/2017' 
            AND (C.EndDate >= '10/01/2017' OR C.EndDate IS NULL)
        )  A1
    WHERE A1.RestartCase = 'Y'
ORDER BY A1.Per_ID
    ) A2`

Comment: Edited the above SQL. Try that?

Comment: ...putting conditions in the `WHERE` clause like that makes the `LEFT JOIN Person` act like a regular `(INNER) JOIN`.  And unless you're testing if a condition is null (unfulfilled), pretty much all conditions belong in the `ON` clause with joins.

Comment: @EzraJustinLee I want to apply ReportCase = Y to only min and max date columns. Not to all Query

Answer (score 0):

Consider a conditional `CASE` inline aggregate in your window functions to combine both attempted resultsets:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.Per_ID, P.DOB, C.BeginDate, C.EndDate, C.RestartCase, P.per_type,  
                MIN(CASE WHEN C.RestartCase = 'Y' THEN C.BeginDate END)
                              OVER (PARTITION BY C.Per_ID) AS Min_BeginDate,
                MAX(CASE WHEN C.RestartCase = 'Y' THEN C.BeginDate END)
                              OVER (PARTITION BY C.Per_ID) AS Max_BeginDate    
FROM CaseSum C 
LEFT JOIN PERSON P on C.ID_PRSN = P.ID_PRSN
WHERE P.per_Type = 1 AND C.BeginDate <= '9/30/2017' 
  AND (C.EndDate >= '10/01/2017' OR C.EndDate IS NULL)
ORDER BY C.Per_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to apply ReportCase = Y to only min and max date columns. Not to all Query